# Featured based image alignment issue

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to learn OpenCV in order to improve a script I wrote for comparing engineering drawings. I am using the code (see below) found on [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/) tutorial but I am having zero success with it. In the tutorial the author uses the example of a blank form for the reference image and a photo of the completed form as the image to align. My situation is very similar because I am attempting to use a blank drawing title block as my reference image and a scanned image of a drawing as my image to align.

My goal is to use OpenCV to clean up the scanned engineering drawings so that they are aligned properly but no matter what I try in the MAX_FEATURES and GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT parameters, I get an image that looks like a black and white star burst. Also, when I review the "matches.jpg" file generated by the script, it appears that there are no correct matches. I have tried multiple drawings and I get the same results.

Can anyone see a reason why this script would not work in the way I am trying to use it?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2
import numpy as np


MAX_FEATURES = 500
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15


def alignImages(im1, im2):

  # Convert images to grayscale
  im1Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  im2Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
  orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)
  keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im1Gray, None)
  keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(im2Gray, None)

  # Match features.
  matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
  matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)

  # Sort matches by score
  matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

  # Remove not so good matches
  numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
  matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

  # Draw top matches
  imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, None)
  cv2.imwrite("matches.jpg", imMatches)

  # Extract location of good matches
  points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
  points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

  for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
    points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

  # Find homography
  h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

  # Use homography
  height, width, channels = im2.shape
  im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))

  return im1Reg, h


if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Read reference image
  refFilename = "form.jpg"
  print("Reading reference image : ", refFilename)
  imReference = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

  # Read image to be aligned
  imFilename = "scanned-form.jpg"
  print("Reading image to align : ", imFilename);  
  im = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

  print("Aligning images ...")
  # Registered image will be resotred in imReg. 
  # The estimated homography will be stored in h. 
  imReg, h = alignImages(im, imReference)

  # Write aligned image to disk. 
  outFilename = "aligned.jpg"
  print("Saving aligned image : ", outFilename); 
  cv2.imwrite(outFilename, imReg)

  # Print estimated homography
  print("Estimated homography : \n",  h)
```

Template Image:
[image: template]

Image to Align:
[image: scanned drawing]

Expected output Image:
[image]

Comment: Could you add an input and expected output image?

Comment: I've added images to the original post. The first image is the blank title block that I'm using as my reference. The second image is the image I would like to realign, and the third image is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Perhaps threshold your images and use some morphology to thicken the lines. Then if that works, use the same transformation on your original images.  I would also suggest that you use a rigid affine transformation rather than a perspective one.

Comment: For rigid affine, see https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga1aa357007eaec11e9ed03500ecbcbe47

Comment: Also see https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad767faff73e9cbd8b9d92b955b50062d

Comment: Also see https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga762cbe5efd52cf078950196f3c616d48

Answer (score 5):

**Here is one way in Python/OpenCV using a Rigid Affine Transformation** (scale, rotation and translation only - no skew or perspective) to warp one image to match the other. It uses findTransformECC() -- Enhanced Correlation Coefficient Maximization) -- to get the rotation matrix and then uses warpAffine to do the rigid warping.

Template:

[image]

Image to be warped:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import sys

# Get the image files from the command line arguments
# These are full paths to the images
# image2 will be warped to match image1
# argv[0] is name of script
image1 = sys.argv[1]
image2 = sys.argv[2]
outfile = sys.argv[3]

# Read the images to be aligned
# im2 is to be warped to match im1
im1 =  cv2.imread(image1);
im2 =  cv2.imread(image2);

# Convert images to grayscale for computing the rotation via ECC method
im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find size of image1
sz = im1.shape

# Define the motion model - euclidean is rigid (SRT)
warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_EUCLIDEAN

# Define 2x3 matrix and initialize the matrix to identity matrix I (eye)
warp_matrix = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)

# Specify the number of iterations.
number_of_iterations = 5000;

# Specify the threshold of the increment
# in the correlation coefficient between two iterations
termination_eps = 1e-3;

# Define termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, number_of_iterations,  termination_eps)

# Run the ECC algorithm. The results are stored in warp_matrix.
(cc, warp_matrix) = cv2.findTransformECC (im1_gray, im2_gray, warp_matrix, warp_mode, criteria, None, 1)

# Warp im2 using affine
im2_aligned = cv2.warpAffine(im2, warp_matrix, (sz[1],sz[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP);

# write output
cv2.imwrite(outfile, im2_aligned)

# Print rotation angle
row1_col0 = warp_matrix[0,1]
angle = math.degrees(math.asin(row1_col0))
print(angle)
```

Result:

[image]

Resulting Angle of Rotation (in deg):

```
-0.3102187026194794
```

Note, you can change the background color in the affineWarp to white if desired.

Also make the termination epsilon smaller by an order of magnitude or two for more accuracy, but longer processing times.

**The other Rigid Affine approach that I mentioned in my comments earlier is** to use ORB feature matching, filter the key points, then use estimateAffinePartial2D() to get the rigid affine matrix. Then use that to warp the image. For large angles this seems to me to be more reliable than the ECC method. But the ECC method seems more accurate for small rotations.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import sys


MAX_FEATURES = 10000
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15
DIFFY_THRESH = 2

# Get the image files from the command line arguments
# These are full paths to the images
# image[2] will be warped to match image[1]
# argv[0] is name of script
file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]
outFile = sys.argv[3]

# Read image1
image1 = cv2.imread(file1, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Read image2 to be warped to match image1
image2 = cv2.imread(file2, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Convert images to grayscale
image1Gray = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image2Gray = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)
keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(image1Gray, None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(image2Gray, None)

# Match features.
matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)

# Sort matches by score
matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

# Remove not so good matches
numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]
#print('numgood',numGoodMatches)

# Extract location of good matches and filter by diffy if rotation is small
points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt
    points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

# initialize empty arrays for newpoints1 and newpoints2 and mask
newpoints1 = np.empty(shape=[0, 2], dtype=np.float32)
newpoints2 = np.empty(shape=[0, 2], dtype=np.float32)
matches_Mask = [0] * len(matches)

count=0
for i in range(len(matches)):
    pt1 = points1[i]
    pt2 = points2[i]
    pt1x, pt1y = zip(*[pt1])
    pt2x, pt2y = zip(*[pt2])
    diffy = np.float32( np.float32(pt2y) - np.float32(pt1y) )
    if abs(diffy) < DIFFY_THRESH:
        newpoints1 = np.append(newpoints1, [pt1], axis=0).astype(np.uint8)
        newpoints2 = np.append(newpoints2, [pt2], axis=0).astype(np.uint8)
        matches_Mask[i]=1
        count += 1

# Find Affine Transformation
# note swap of order of newpoints here so that image2 is warped to match image1
m, inliers = cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(newpoints2,newpoints1)

# Use affine transform to warp im2 to match im1
height, width, channels = image1.shape
image2Reg = cv2.warpAffine(image2, m, (width, height))

# Write aligned image to disk. 
cv2.imwrite(outFile, image2Reg)

# Print angle
row1_col0 = m[1,0]
print('row1_col0:',row1_col0)
angle = math.degrees(math.asin(row1_col0))
print('angle', angle)
```

Result Image:

[image]

Result Rotation Angle:

```
-0.6123936361765413
```

Comment: The first script works, but I receive the following error with the second script and I don't quite understand the problem: 

imgwarp.cpp:2603: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 2 && M0.cols == 3 in function 'cv::warpAffine'

Comment: Got it working by adjusting the DIFFY_THRESH, but I'm still having an issue with both scripts. The rotations are correct but the images are still not aligned. Basically I need the corners of the drawing frame of the scanned image to match the corners of the image of the reference image. My end goal is to create an overlay of the two images to highlight the differences (see my script here: https://github.com/HyGear/diff-dwg), but this is difficult unless the images are reasonably aligned. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think you will get them perfectly aligned so that you can subtract the template from the other image to get only the changes. It is very difficult to get such accuracy with such thin lines.

Comment: After trying several things and playing around with different methods, I believe I have found something that will work for my purposes. 

I was able to use the Harris corner finding algorithm to find all of the corners of the drawing title block, then did a distance calculation from the corners of the drawing canvas to find the outside corners of the drawing title block. I did this for both drawings (old and new revisions) and was able to use an affine transformation to rotate and scale the new revision points to the old revision points so that the images line up properly.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error I determined that I don't need to find a homography in order to align my images properly. Since my images only need to be scaled and rotated slightly, my best option is to find the outer most points of the drawing title block and align one image to the other with a transform.

My approach is to use the Harris corner finding function to find all of the corners on the drawing, then do a simple calculation to find the points that are the shortest distance to the corners of the drawing canvas (these are the outside corners of the drawing title block). I then take 3 of the points (top left, top right, and bottom left) and use a transform to scale/rotate one drawing to the other.

Below is the code that I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

img1 = cv2.imread('reference.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('to-be-aligned.jpg')

#Find the corner points of img1
h1,w1,c=img1.shape
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray1 = np.float32(gray1)
dst1 = cv2.cornerHarris(gray1,5,3,0.04)
ret1, dst1 = cv2.threshold(dst1,0.1*dst1.max(),255,0)
dst1 = np.uint8(dst1)
ret1, labels1, stats1, centroids1 = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst1)
criteria1 = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
corners1 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray1,np.float32(centroids1),(5,5),(-1,-1),criteria1)

#Find the corner points of img2
h2,w2,c=img2.shape
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = np.float32(gray2)
dst2 = cv2.cornerHarris(gray2,5,3,0.04)
ret2, dst2 = cv2.threshold(dst2,0.1*dst2.max(),255,0)
dst2 = np.uint8(dst2)
ret2, labels2, stats2, centroids2 = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst2)
criteria2 = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray2,np.float32(centroids2),(5,5),(-1,-1),criteria2)


#Find the top left, top right, and bottom left outer corners of the drawing frame for img1
a1=[0,0]
b1=[w1,0]
c1=[0,h1]
a1_dist=[]
b1_dist=[]
c1_dist=[]
for i in corners1:
    temp_a1=math.sqrt((i[0]-a1[0])**2+(i[1]-a1[1])**2)
    temp_b1=math.sqrt((i[0]-b1[0])**2+(i[1]-b1[1])**2)
    temp_c1=math.sqrt((i[0]-c1[0])**2+(i[1]-c1[1])**2)
    a1_dist.append(temp_a1)
    b1_dist.append(temp_b1)
    c1_dist.append(temp_c1)

print("Image #1 (reference):")
print("Top Left:")
print(corners1[a1_dist.index(min(a1_dist))])
print("Top Right:")
print(corners1[b1_dist.index(min(b1_dist))])
print("Bottom Left:")
print(corners1[c1_dist.index(min(c1_dist))])

#Find the top left, top right, and bottom left outer corners of the drawing frame for img2
a2=[0,0]
b2=[w2,0]
c2=[0,h2]
a2_dist=[]
b2_dist=[]
c2_dist=[]
for i in corners2:
    temp_a2=math.sqrt((i[0]-a2[0])**2+(i[1]-a2[1])**2)
    temp_b2=math.sqrt((i[0]-b2[0])**2+(i[1]-b2[1])**2)
    temp_c2=math.sqrt((i[0]-c2[0])**2+(i[1]-c2[1])**2)
    a2_dist.append(temp_a2)
    b2_dist.append(temp_b2)
    c2_dist.append(temp_c2)

print("Image #2 (image to align):")
print("Top Left:")
print(corners2[a2_dist.index(min(a2_dist))])
print("Top Right:")
print(corners2[b2_dist.index(min(b2_dist))])
print("Bottom Left:")
print(corners2[c2_dist.index(min(c2_dist))])

#Create the points for img1
point1 = np.zeros((3,2), dtype=np.float32)
point1[0][0]=corners1[a1_dist.index(min(a1_dist))][0]
point1[0][1]=corners1[a1_dist.index(min(a1_dist))][1]
point1[1][0]=corners1[b1_dist.index(min(b1_dist))][0]
point1[1][1]=corners1[b1_dist.index(min(b1_dist))][1]
point1[2][0]=corners1[c1_dist.index(min(c1_dist))][0]
point1[2][1]=corners1[c1_dist.index(min(c1_dist))][1]

#Create the points for img2
point2 = np.zeros((3,2), dtype=np.float32)
point2[0][0]=corners2[a2_dist.index(min(a2_dist))][0]
point2[0][1]=corners2[a2_dist.index(min(a2_dist))][1]
point2[1][0]=corners2[b2_dist.index(min(b2_dist))][0]
point2[1][1]=corners2[b2_dist.index(min(b2_dist))][1]
point2[2][0]=corners2[c2_dist.index(min(c2_dist))][0]
point2[2][1]=corners2[c2_dist.index(min(c2_dist))][1]

#Make sure points look ok:
print(point1)
print(point2)

#Transform the image
m = cv2.getAffineTransform(point2,point1)
image2Reg = cv2.warpAffine(img2, m, (w1, h1), borderValue=(255,255,255))

#Highlight found points in red:
img1[dst1>0.1*dst1.max()]=[0,0,255]
img2[dst2>0.1*dst2.max()]=[0,0,255]

#Output the images:
cv2.imwrite("output-img1-harris.jpg", img1)
cv2.imwrite("output-img2-harris.jpg", img2)
cv2.imwrite("output-harris-transform.jpg",image2Reg)
```