# OpenCV: How to extract the inner area of a series of rectangles that are arranged in a particular way?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, omr

I have a series of images which are like the image A. My intention is to detect the inner area of each rectangle and extract that area for further processing; so what I need are the position (x,y) and dimension (width,height) of the the areas which are shown with green in image B.

[image]

My current approach (which works just fine) is that I have created a PNG overlay of the areas that I need which have a specific color (image C), put the PNG overlay on top of the source image (with the hardcoded x,y), Performing a basic thresholding operation on the overlaid image using OpenCV to create a mask, finding all the contours, getting the position (x,y) and dimension (width,height) of all the matches and finally cropping those areas on the original image.

```
#defining the mask color
magenta_color = np.uint8([[[255, 0, 255]]])
hsv_magenta = cv2.cvtColor(magenta_color,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_magenta = np.array(hsv_magenta[0][0])
upper_magenta = np.array(hsv_magenta[0][0])

#loading images
image_source = cv2.imread("source_image.png")
image_overlay = cv2.imread("overlay_image.png")

#putting overlay on top of original image at the correct position
image_overlaid = add_image(image_source, image_overlay, 20, 35)


#thresholding and finding the matches
image_overlaid = cv2.cvtColor(image_overlaid, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
masked = cv2.inRange(image_overlaid, lower_magenta, upper_magenta)
all_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(masked, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#getting the x, y, width, height of each match
for contour in all_contours:
    x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    
    #cropping the area on the original image
    area = image_source[y:y + height, x:x + width]
```

As I said, the approach that I use works but it is very fragile because I should know (beforehand) the exact (x,y) position of overlay image and both source image and overlay image should match perfectly (in terms of position of rectangles and their dimensions).

I also tried to look for all the rectangles in the image (again using `cv2.findContours`) and use the found contours for getting the needed areas but as image A is evident, the black color has bled over many rectangles so I cannot check if a contour is actually a rectangle.

```
image_source = cv2.imread("source_image.png")
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_binary_inverse = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 255, 10)
image_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image_binary_inverse, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in image_contours:
    cv2.drawContours(image_source, [contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

[image]

Is there a better approach for achieving what I intend that doesn't have the drawbacks of what I currently use (PNG overlay)?

**Note:** I have control over the generation process of the layout of the rectangles (or whatever that can be added to the layout before being filled)

Comment: You might use an image free of markings and register each marked image to that image. If you know the locations of the boxes in the image free of the markings, then you can crop the marked image using those coordinates. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654471/featured-based-image-alignment-issue/59655966#59655966

Comment: @fmw42 "If you know the locations of the boxes in the image", that's the whole point of question. How to get/calculate the location of the boxes and not using precoded values.

Comment: That is not what I am saying. I am saying to use a perfect template image. Then get the location of the empty boxes (perhaps using contours and their bounding boxes). Now register any filled in test image to the perfect image. Now just crop all the boxes and look for filled ones. You already have the locations of each box.

Comment: ok, suppose that I used a perfect template image (free of markings), and yes, I can now, know the location and dimension of the boxes. but I still have the problem of matching the data with the imperfect image (in the sense that for example in perfect template box1 is at `x1,y1` but in imperfect image it maybe at `x1+10,y1-5` locations)
**This is basically what I'm doing with PNG overlay.**

Comment: As I said above see warping the one image to match the other -- for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654471/featured-based-image-alignment-issue/59655966#59655966