# Using homography to transform an image in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a project so that I can extract data from scanned datasheets, however,I'm having problems making the code work as while there are no errors, it doesn't appear to do anything to transform the image.

Below is the template image and on the and beneath that is a scanned skewed image that I would like to use homography techniques to transform to matcxh the template image

[image: Template image]
[image: Scanned skewed image]

The python script  I have been working on doesn't show any errors, yet also doesn't appear to perform any transformations on the image. How the script is supposed to work is it identifies the aruco markers, creates a mask around each of the markers then uses orb to find features in the masks of both images before using bfmatcher to find the best matches between each of the masks before using the findhomography and warpperspective functions from cv2 to estimate and perform the transformation

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def resize_image(image, desired_width=None, desired_height=None):
    """Resize an image while maintaining aspect ratio."""
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if desired_width is not None and desired_height is None:
        r = desired_width / float(w)
        dim = (desired_width, int(h * r))
    elif desired_height is not None and desired_width is None:
        r = desired_height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), desired_height)
    else:
        dim = (desired_width, desired_height)

    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

#min number of matches to perform transform
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

# template and image to be adjusted
template_image = 'C:/projects/manta AI/datasheets/blankaruco_gap.jpg'
template = cv2.imread(template_image)
desired_height = 1024
template = resize_image(template, desired_height=desired_height)
gray_template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

new_image = cv2.imread("C:\projects\manta AI\datasheets/skewedaruco_gap.jpg")
new_image = resize_image(new_image, desired_height=desired_height)
gray_new_image = cv2.cvtColor(new_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# detect arucco markers
aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
corners_template, _, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(gray_template, aruco_dict)
corners_new_image, _, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(gray_new_image, aruco_dict)

# create masks around the aruco markers
mask_template = np.zeros_like(gray_template)
mask_new_image = np.zeros_like(gray_new_image)

for corner in corners_template:
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask_template, corner[0].astype(int), 1)

for corner in corners_new_image:
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask_new_image, corner[0].astype(int), 1)

#  orb detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=2000)

# Detect keypoints in masked regions
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray_template, mask=mask_template)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray_new_image, mask=mask_new_image)

# use bfmatfcher to find two best matches per describptor
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

# Lowe's ratio test
good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

# use transfrm to  warp image
if len(good_matches) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(template, M, (new_image.shape[1], new_image.shape[0]))
else:
    print("Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good_matches), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    warped_image = new_image

# Display using matplotlib
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(warped_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Warped Image')
plt.show()
```

Any and all ideas would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try cv2.findTransformECC(). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654471/featured-based-image-alignment-issue/59655966#59655966

Comment: why on earth would you deploy ORB and feature matching when you have AR markers on the page? they're there FOR localization of the sheet. did you not put them there yourself? what's the reason? you merely find and erase them. there is no point to this. -- besides, ORB is terrible. use a sensible descriptor like SIFT or AKAZE or whatever else is competitive -- @fmw42 that requires a reasonably close initial transform. it's for refinement, not for finding the transform in the first place. the function is named badly.

Comment: `@Christoph Rackwitz` Thanks for the comment/correction. Also I had not noticed the AR markers. Did not pay enough attention.

Comment: well who put the markers there? where does the script come from?

Comment: I put the markers there, initially I wanted to align via QR codes, however I had trouble detecting those, so I tried the more robust aruco markers but also with no luck. So i tried SIFT and SURF however it threw up a licensing error so I tried ORB, I decided to leave the markers on there as I figured they would provide addition "hooks" for the matcher to find

Comment: Basically the script has become a patchwork of different methods

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a scan, perspective distortion is not to be expected.

You have three markers. Their centers can be reliably located.

Using all 3*4=12 corners for a perspective transform is inadvisable. The corners are too close together, while still having noise on the order of a pixel or so. This would introduce a ***spurious*** perspective component, as shown in the other answer (the unwarped scan does not align with the template).

```
im_template = cv.imread("BccPH.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im_scan = cv.imread("NuyTB.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

aruco stuff:

```
arucodict = cv.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv.aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
arucoparams = cv.aruco.DetectorParameters()
detector = cv.aruco.ArucoDetector(arucodict, arucoparams)

def get_marker_centers(image):
    markers, ids, rej = detector.detectMarkers(image)
    return {
        id: marker.mean(axis=0) # affine transform, average is center
        for [id], [marker] in sorted(zip(ids, markers))
    }
```

Getting the markers:

```
markers_template = get_marker_centers(im_template)
markers_scan = get_marker_centers(im_scan)

assert markers_template.keys() == markers_scan.keys()
ids_ordered = sorted(markers_template.keys())

markers_template = np.array([markers_template[id] for id in ids_ordered])
markers_scan = np.array([markers_scan[id] for id in ids_ordered])
```

Estimating an affine transform.

`Partial2D` declared one corner to be an outlier. Seems like the transform has some anisotropic scaling.

```
#M, inliers = cv.estimateAffinePartial2D(markers_scan, markers_template) # translation, rotation, scaling
M, inliers = cv.estimateAffine2D(markers_template, markers_scan) # full affine

print(inliers.T)
print(M)

h,w = im_template.shape[:2]

im_scan_unwarped = cv.warpAffine(
    im_scan, M, (w,h),
    flags=cv.INTER_LINEAR | cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP,
    borderMode=cv.BORDER_REPLICATE)
```

```
[[1 1 1]]
[[ 0.50296 -0.01619 -3.40904]
 [ 0.01488  0.49907 18.36688]]
```

So the scan appears scaled down (0.5) and shifted downward (18.37).

`absdiff` of unwarped scan vs template, the unwarped scan:

[image: absdiff]
[image: unwarped]

Now you could apply some ECC refinement to improve the alignment:

```
rv, Mecc = cv.findTransformECC(
    templateImage=im_template,
    inputImage=im_scan,
    warpMatrix=M.astype(np.float32),
    motionType=cv.MOTION_AFFINE,
    criteria=(cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1e-3))

print(rv)
print(M)
print(Mecc)
```

```
0.9397464819681713
[[ 0.50296 -0.01619 -3.40904]
 [ 0.01488  0.49907 18.36688]]
[[ 0.50259 -0.01602 -3.01703]
 [ 0.01478  0.49931 18.10688]]
```

[image: absdiff-ecc]
[image: unwarped-ecc]

This still shows some *position-dependent* disagreement with the template. This is unlikely to be a perspective component. It may be a linear effect or entirely nonlinear (laser printer's mirror speed). Unlocking full perspective *in the ECC refinement* may be worth a try.

ECC refinement benefits from somewhat smooth gradients. A gaussian lowpass on both inputs may improve the result. Sigma on the order of 1 is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In the Below code, I used the aruco markers in the template and skewed image to identify transformation points.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Template Image Details, This need to be found from template manually.
#Original image 610 x 862
#top right of aruco markers
##PLEASE NOTE : I calculated this points after resizing the Template image to  610 x 862 using https://www.mobilefish.com/services/record_mouse_coordinates/record_mouse_coordinates.php
template_width = 610
template_height = 862
original_template_top_rigth_auro_markers={
1:[78,109], #top left marker
2:[538,107], #top right marker
3:[538,793], #bottom right
}
#bottom left of aruco markers
original_template_bottom_left_auro_markers={
1:[44,140], #top left marker
2:[506,139], #top right marker
3:[506,825], #bottom right
}

################ Read Skewed image and get details ##################
image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
input_height,input_width,_ = image.shape


################# Find skewed image aruco markers details ############################

# Need to change the format in different version #
# arucoDict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
# arucoParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
# (corners, ids, rejected) = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image, arucoDict,parameters=arucoParams)

dictionary = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
parameters =  cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
detector = cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector(dictionary, parameters)
corners, ids, rejected = detector.detectMarkers(image)

skewed_top_rigth_auro_markers = {}
skewed_bottom_left_auro_markers ={}

# taken from https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/12/21/detecting-aruco-markers-with-opencv-and-python/
if len(corners) > 0:
    # flatten the ArUco IDs list
    ids = ids.flatten()
    # loop over the detected ArUCo corners
    for (markerCorner, markerID) in zip(corners, ids):
        # extract the marker corners (which are always returned in
        # top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left order)
        corners = markerCorner.reshape((4, 2))
        (topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft) = corners
        # convert each of the (x, y)-coordinate pairs to integers
        topRight = [int(topRight[0]), int(topRight[1])]
        bottomRight = [int(bottomRight[0]), int(bottomRight[1])]
        bottomLeft = [int(bottomLeft[0]), int(bottomLeft[1])]
        topLeft = [int(topLeft[0]), int(topLeft[1])]
        skewed_top_rigth_auro_markers[markerID] =topRight
        skewed_bottom_left_auro_markers[markerID] = bottomLeft

################# Use Skewed image found aruco marker images as Source points and Resized Template aruco marker points as target points #################################
src_pts =  [skewed_top_rigth_auro_markers[1],skewed_top_rigth_auro_markers[2],skewed_top_rigth_auro_markers[3],skewed_bottom_left_auro_markers[1],skewed_bottom_left_auro_markers[2],skewed_bottom_left_auro_markers[3]]
src_pts = np.array(src_pts)
#print("Sorce skewed image points : ", src_pts)

dst_pts = [original_template_top_rigth_auro_markers[1],original_template_top_rigth_auro_markers[2],original_template_top_rigth_auro_markers[3],original_template_bottom_left_auro_markers[1],original_template_bottom_left_auro_markers[2],original_template_bottom_left_auro_markers[3]]
dst_pts = np.array(dst_pts)
#print("Destination template points :", dst_pts)

######################### Use Source and target points to transform image and save ############################################################

mat, some = cv2.findHomography(srcPoints=src_pts, dstPoints=dst_pts)
out = cv2.warpPerspective(image, mat, (template_width, template_height))
cv2.imwrite('converted.jpg',out)
print("Saved image to converted.jpg")
```

> output

[image]